# Import xs:attributeGroups to multiple namespaces xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have an attributeGroup with long list of allowed attributes say a:attr-group, that I import to another xsd to restrict an element's (defined in another xsd) allowed attributes with.

I also want to allow the same element to use the same attributes under a second namespace say b:attr-group, and wish to use the same file (rather than repeat all the attributes and group definition).

Is there a simple way of doing this? All my attempts so far have been thwarted by the import namespace must equal targetNamespace rule.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern is also known as *chameleon*. It means you're **including** an XML Schema that has no target namespace, which in turn makes that schema *assume* the namespace of the *parent* schema.

UPDATE: considering the sample XML provided in the comments:

First schema file (AttrGroup.xsxd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:attributeGroup name="attr-group">
        <xsd:attribute name="attr1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="attr2" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>
</xsd:schema>
```

Second schema file (A.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a"
xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="AttrGroup.xsd"/>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="a-group">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="attr-group"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

</xsd:schema>
```

Third schema file (B.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b"
xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="AttrGroup.xsd"/>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="b-group">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="attr-group"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>
</xsd:schema>
```

Fourth XML Schema (Element.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a" xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a" schemaLocation="A.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b" schemaLocation="B.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="element">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="a:a-group"/>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="b:b-group"/>           
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

[image: XML Schema files layout]

Sample of valid XML:

```
<element xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a" xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b" a:attr1="hello" b:attr2="10" />
```

Sample of invalid XML:

```
<element xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a" xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b" a:attr1="hello" b:attr2="10a" />
```

When validating against Element.xsd the invalid sample, I am getting this error message (on my tool):
Error occurred while loading [], line 1 position 116
The 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b:attr2' attribute is invalid - The value '10a' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:int' - The string '10a' is not a valid Int32 value.
D:...\SampleAttrGroup.xml is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, doesn't that give me two different element defintions though? Do I need to validate my xml against both schemas independently?

Comment: Can you give me an example of an xml document that would validate against a.xsd and b.xsd I have tried test.xml as: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element xmlns:a="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/a" xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd/b" elementFormDetail="unqualified" a:attr1="a" b:attr2="b"/>` but it cannot resolve 'element'

Comment: Thanks Petru, that does it! Very clear and well presented answer - cheers!