# Unqualified XSD global attribute references

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

The following XML schema fails to validate with following XML instance document. Is there any way to rewrite the schema so the instance document validates, within the given constraints?

### Constraints

- The attribute cannot be local to the element
- The instance document must be unchanged

### (Invalid) Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:attribute name="sample-attribute" type="xs:string" />

    <xs:element name="sample-element">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="sample-attribute" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### Instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sample-element xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" sample-attribute="test" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) states that "The namespace name for an unprefixed attribute name always has no value"; on the other hand you constrained the attribute not to be local, so the only way to do it **(credit goes to @GrahamHannington)** is to wrap it in an attribute group, thus allowing the attribute definition to be reused without being qualified.

Comment: Thanks. Reviewing at the problem from which I derived this example, it makes more sense to handle it with custom types instead of attributes anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

Wrap the (global) `xs:attribute` element in an `xs:attributeGroup` element.

In the `xs:element` element, refer to the `xs:attributeGroup` element.

The `name` attribute of the `xs:attributeGroup` element can have the same value as the `name` attribute of the `xs:attribute` element.

## Schema

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:attributeGroup name="sample-attribute">
      <xs:attribute name="sample-attribute" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

    <xs:element name="sample-element">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="sample-attribute" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## Information not directly related to the question

This is not an extension to the answer above, nor an alternative answer, just related information that you might find helpful (it is not within the constraints of your question).

You could leave your original schema untouched, and explicitly qualify (add a namespace prefix to) the attribute name in the document instance, like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<t:sample-element
    xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    t:sample-attribute="test"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd sample.xsd"/>
```

(Note the `t:` namespace prefix on both the root element name and the attribute name.)

Comment: @Petru has a point about "forcing it [the attribute] to have a qualified name", but the question can be answered affirmatively within the given constraints (for details, see my answer).

Comment: +1, you are absolutely correct, can't think of how I've missed it! I obviously knew that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166445/import-xsattributegroups-to-multiple-namespaces-xsd/8166703#8166703) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865247/xsd-factor-out-multiple-use-attribute/11871782#11871782)... must've been blinded by the first constraint.