# xsd factor out multiple use attribute

Tags: xsd, refactoring

I'm not sure how to factor out this piece of XSD:

```
<xs:attribute name="status" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="not run"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="passed"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="failed"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

which is needed in both `<test>` and `<step>` tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="FlowBi:Emis:FeatureTests" 
xmlns="FlowBi:Emis:FeatureTests" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="featureTests">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="test" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence> 
                        <xs:element name="summary" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="step" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="status" use="required">
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="not run"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="passed"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="failed"/>
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                            </xs:attribute>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="status" use="required">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                                <xs:enumeration value="not run"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="passed"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="failed"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It would be nice to factor out the repeated section and just reference it in each place it is used but I'm not sure how to do this for attribute types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2012 Developer Edition 10.1.2.4113 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns="FlowBi:Emis:FeatureTests" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="FlowBi:Emis:FeatureTests" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="featureTests">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="test" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="summary" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="step" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:simpleContent>
                                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:attribute name="status" type="statusType" use="required" />
                                            </xs:extension>
                                        </xs:simpleContent>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="status" type="statusType" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="statusType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="not run" />
            <xs:enumeration value="passed" />
            <xs:enumeration value="failed" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Sprotty is correct (+1). I would add clarifications/variations that don't fit into comments (hence the answer)...

Typically, the reason why only the simple type was reused by Sprotty has to do with how attributes are commonly unqualified in an XSD. Since the attributes are unqualified in your example, reusing the whole attribute is possible only if the attribute is wrapped under an attributeGroup. Basically reusing a globally defined attribute means qualifying the attribute.

So, this is another possibility that re-uses the attribute declaration (as opposed to the simple type only):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="FlowBi:Emis:FeatureTests" xmlns="FlowBi:Emis:FeatureTests" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="featureTests">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="test" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="summary" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="step" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="gaStatus" />
                                                </xs:extension>
                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attributeGroup ref="gaStatus" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="gaStatus">
        <xs:attribute name="status" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:enumeration value="not run"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="passed"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="failed"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>         
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```