# Error while validating XML

Tags: c#, .net, xsd-validation

System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be undefined

StackTrace:

```
   at System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute..ctor(XName name, Object value)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XNodeValidator.ValidateAttributes(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XNodeValidator.ValidateElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XNodeValidator.ValidateNodes(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XNodeValidator.ValidateElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XNodeValidator.Validate(XObject source, XmlSchemaObject partialValidationType, Boolean addSchemaInfo)
   at System.Xml.Schema.Extensions.Validate(XDocument source, XmlSchemaSet schemas, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler, Boolean addSchemaInfo)
```

Source code:

```
    var xmlPath = @"C:\XSDTEST\test.xml";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
    XmlSchemaSet xss = new XmlSchemaSet();

    xss.Add("",@"C:\XSDTEST\test.xsd");

    XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
    xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints;
    xrs.Schemas = xss;

    doc.Validate(xss, new ValidationEventHandler((s, args) => { }), true);
```

test.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Child1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element ref="Child2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Child2" type="Child2ElemType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Child2ElemType">
        <xsd:attribute ref="align" default="left"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:attribute name="align" type="alignAttType"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="alignAttType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
            <xsd:enumeration value="left"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="right"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="center"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="justify"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="char"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

test.xml:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/XSDTEST/test.xsd">
    <Child1/>
    <Child2/>
</Root>
```

The problem: default="left":

```
<xsd:attribute ref="align" default="left"/>
```

I think the validation process tries to create an "align" attribute with a default value, but the XAttribute constructor gets null, not "left".

If I set default value at `<xsd:attribute name="align" type="alignAttType" default="left"/>` it works fine.

If I set default value at `<xsd:attribute ref="align" default="left"/>` I will get the error.

Can I disable the creation of attributes with default values during the validation process?

or

What are the settings for correctly handling the default values?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the XSD, the "ref=" must be a "Qualified Name"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256143(v=vs.110).aspx

> The ref value **must** be a qualified name (QName)

Since you have an XSD without a namespace, it looks like the validator is not able to find the referenced attribute.

Also, take a look at this related SO question:
[How to reference an attribute in xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025859/how-to-reference-an-attribute-in-xsd)

> in XML Schemas all global element, attribute or type definitions must be qualified

The following is the relevant Standard extract:
https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting

> Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names
>
> The namespace name for an unprefixed attribute name always has no value

The following link talks specifically about the unqualified global attributes
[Unqualified XSD global attribute references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903768/unqualified-xsd-global-attribute-references)

Comment: I have unmanaged official schemas for validation. I cant change schema.

Answer (score 0):

After loading schemas I founded temporary workaround:

```
       foreach (XmlSchema schema in xss.Schemas())
            {
                foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry ag in schema.AttributeGroups)
                {
                    if (ag.Value is XmlSchemaAttributeGroup)
                    {
                        var attributeGroup = (XmlSchemaAttributeGroup)ag.Value;


                        foreach (var attributeOrGroup in attributeGroup.Attributes)
                        {
                            if (attributeOrGroup is XmlSchemaAttribute)
                            {
                                var attribute = (XmlSchemaAttribute)attributeOrGroup;
                                if (attribute.DefaultValue != null)
                                {
                                    attribute.DefaultValue = null;
                                }
                                if (attribute.FixedValue != null)
                                {
                                    attribute.FixedValue = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry st in schema.SchemaTypes)
                {
                    if (st.Value is XmlSchemaComplexType)
                    {
                        var c = (XmlSchemaComplexType)st.Value;

                        foreach (var g in c.Attributes)
                        {
                            if (g is XmlSchemaAttribute)
                            {
                                var attr = (XmlSchemaAttribute)g;
                                if (attr.DefaultValue != null)
                                {
                                    attr.DefaultValue = null;

                                }
                                if (attr.FixedValue != null)
                                {
                                    attr.FixedValue = null;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```